# How to continuously show os command output in erlang?

Tags: operating-system, erlang

I need continuously show stdout/stderr from os command in erlang.
In ruby I can implement it with following code:

```
s1, s2 , s3, t = Open3.popen3('for %a in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do (echo message & sleep 2 ) 2>&1 ')

s2.each do |l|
    puts l
end
```

it will show 'message\n message\n' in 'real time' - does not wait end of process.

I've tried `os:cmd(..)`
and

```
1> P5 = erlang:open_port({spawn, "ruby rtest.rb"}, [stderr_to_stdout, in, exit_s
tatus, binary,stream, {line, 255}]).
#Port<0.505>
2> receive {P5, Data} -> io:format("Data ~p~n",[Data]) end.
Data {data,{eol,<<>>}}
ok
```

but both of them wait end of process.

Are the any optional for continuously stdout reading in Erlang?

**EDIT:**
In other words I look for a popen (c/c++; proc_open(php) and etc) function in erlang

**EDIT2**
Code, that works on linux (tested on centos6.2). Thanks for `vinod`:

```
-module(test).
-export([run/0]).


run() ->  
    P5 = erlang:open_port({spawn, "sh test.sh"}, 
    [stderr_to_stdout, in, exit_status,stream, {line, 255}]), 
    loop(P5).

loop(P) ->
       receive{P, Data} -> 
           io:format("Data ~p~n",[Data]),
       loop(P)
       end.
```

Output:

```
10> c(test).
{ok,test}
11> test:run().
Data {data,{eol,"1"}}
Data {data,{eol,"2"}}
Data {data,{eol,"3"}}
Data {data,{eol,"4"}}
Data {data,{eol,"5"}}
Data {data,{eol,"6"}}
Data {data,{eol,"7"}}
Data {data,{eol,"8"}}
Data {data,{eol,"9"}}
Data {data,{eol,"10"}}
Data {exit_status,0}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to continue to execute your program in concurrent with the os command. In Erlang you can just spawn a process which does that and you can continue. For example

```
1> spawn(fun() ->  
       P5 = erlang:open_port({spawn, "ruby rtest.rb"}, 
                             [stderr_to_stdout, in, exit_status, 
                              binary,stream, {line, 255}]), 
       receive {P5, Data} -> 
           io:format("Data ~p~n",[Data]) 
       end  
   end).
<0.32.0>
2> 5+5.
10
3>
```

Better to write in a module so that you can understand it better.

Comment: That is not that I need. I need to get command output without waiting of end of command. For example ruby code in the top of the page allows to print output line from opened process at the same time when process  prints it to own stderr or stdout.

Comment: The above code also does the same thing. The spawned process prints the output at the same time the spawning process (here shell process) continues to print. Here you are creating another Erlang process which exclusively waits for the data from the OS process and prints it while spawning Erlang process continues to print at the same time.

Comment: Tried on windows 7 x64. What OS do you use?

Comment: Tried on centos6.2 - you are absolutely correct, it works! Thank you!